# How do I combine the contents of two lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two `List<int>` instances.  Now I want to combine them into a third list.

```
public List<int> oldItemarry1 // storing old item
{
    get 
    { 
        return (List<int>)ViewState["oldItemarry1 "]; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        ViewState["oldItemarry1 "] = value; 
    }
}

public List<int> newItemarry1 // storing new item
{
    get
    { 
        return (List<int>)ViewState["newItemarry1 "]; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        ViewState["newItemarry1 "] = value; 
    }
}

public List<int> Itemarry1 // want to combine both the item
{
    get
    { 
        return (List<int>)ViewState["Itemarry1 "]; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        ViewState["Itemarry1 "] = value; 
    }
}
```

Please some one tell me how to do that?

Comment: Do you need a setter on Itemarry1? Also, what do you want to occur if someone adds an entry to any of the first two lists (do you expect it also to be added to the third list)? Using the techniques listed here by everyone will give you a 'point in time' concatentation of the lists - it won't be live. Even more complicated - what do you expect to occur if the user adds an item to the third (combined) list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) method; it will exclude duplicates.

```
int[] combinedWithoutDups = oldItemarry1.Union(newItemarry1).ToArray();
```

Comment: And Concat will include duplicates if you want that.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: oldItemarry1 i am getting 0 and only i am getting newItemarry1, so its not getting added, oldItemarry1 i am getting on page load and new itemarray i am getting when i am adding the item, after adding the item i want to combine both old and new itemarray1

Comment: @Rocky, I'm afraid I didn't follow what your problem is, but I promise you, calling oldItemarry1.Union(newItemarry1) will combine the elements of both an return a unique collection.

Comment: can i do list this List<int> combinedWithoutDups = oldItemarray1.Union(newItemarray1).ToList();

Comment: @Rocky - yes, you most certainly can do that.

Comment: thanks Adam its working, I was doing some mistake at the time of loading only. thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5428/discussion-between-rocky-and-adam-rackis)

Answer (score 5):

LINQ has the Concat method:

```
return oldItemarry1.Concat(newItemarry1).ToList();
```

That just puts the list together.  LINQ also has `Intersect` method, which will give you only items that exist in both lists and the `Except` method, which only gives you items that are present in either, but not both.  The `Union` method give you all items between the two lists, but no duplicates like the `Concat` method.

If LINQ is not an option, you can just create a new list, add the items from each list to both via `AddRange`, and return that.

EDIT:

Since LINQ is not an option, you can do it a few ways:

Combine lists with all items, including duplicates:

```
var newList = new List<int>();
newList.AddRange(first);
newList.AddRange(second);
return newList
```

Combine without duplicate items

```
var existingItems = new HashSet<int>();
var newList = new List<int>();

existingItems.UnionWith(firstList);
existingItems.UnionWith(secondList);
newList.AddRange(existingItems);

return newList;
```

This of course assumes that you're using .NET 4.0, since that is when `HashSet<T>` was introduced.  It's a shame you aren't using Linq, it really excels at things like this.

Comment: @Rocky - From what I read, you are trying to use the `Union` method to get the job done via @Adam's answer, which is part of Linq.  So, I suppose the question is, can you or can you not use Linq?  Keep in mind Linq is **NOT** only used in SQL.  Linq to objects is for use on any collection that implements IEnumerable (arrays, lists, sets, collections, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two lists:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
result.AddRange(oldList1);
result.AddRange(oldList2);
```

The list `result` now has all the elements of both lists.

Comment: on page load i am getting oldlist, and new list i am getting when i am getting new items, now both the items i want to add

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to approach it:

```
public List<int> Itemarry1()
{
    List<int> combinedItems = new List<int>();

    combinedItems.AddRange(oldItemarray1);
    combinedItems.AddRange(newItemarray1);

    return combinedItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, try to use IEnumerable rather than List when you can.  Then, to make this work best you will want a read-only property:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Itemarry1 // want to combine both the item
{
    get
    { 
        return ((List<int>)ViewState["oldItemarry1 "]).Concat((List<int>)ViewState["Itemarry1"]); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a point in time combination of two lists into a third list, `Union` and `Concat` are appropriate, as mentioned by others.

If you want a 'live' combination of the two lists (such that changes to the first and second list are automatically reflected in the 'combined' list) then you may want to look into [Bindable LINQ](http://bindablelinq.codeplex.com/) or [Obtics](http://obtics.codeplex.com/).